# Video and Rich Media feature in SP 2013

Tags: video-richmedia

[image]

Is "Video and Rich Media" feature available in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. Unfortunately it is not part of Foundation (and I'm missing it a lot).